# Scala for loop on Seq of objects within Object

Tags: scala, slick, scala-collections

I have the following Case Class

```
case class BusinessInput(userId: String, name: String, location: Point, address: Option[String], phonenumber: Option[String], email: Option[String], hours: Seq[BusinessHoursInput])
```

And the following BusinessHours Case Class:

```
case class BusinessHoursInput(weekDay: Int, startTime: Time, endTime: Time)
```

I am using Slick and i am trying to add a BusinessHours Row to the DB for each BusinessHoursinput object in the hours field of BusinessInput. I have tried the following:

```
_ <- for(businessHours <- businessInput.hours) BusinessHours += BusinessHoursRow(businessRow.businessId, businessHours.weekDay, businessHours.startTime, businessHours.endTime)
```

but I am stuck on the following error:

```
 value map is not a member of Unit
[error]     _ <- for(businessHours <- businessInput.hours) BusinessHours += BusinessHoursRow(businessRow.businessId, businessHours.weekDay, businessHours.startTime, businessHours.endTime )
[error]                            ^
```

EDIT:

Here is the create function of my Repo, where I am first trying to insert a BusinessRow object and then fetch the autoincremented Id from that insert and insert a list of businessHours objects With the Business Id from the previously inserted Business Object. And then I want to return the Business Object that I first Inserted:

```
def create(businessInput: BusinessInput): Future[BusinessRow] = db.run(for {
  // We create a projection of just the Business Columns, since we're not inserting a value for the id column
   businessRow <- (Business.map(b => (b.userId, b.name, b.location, b.address, b.phonenumber, b.email))
  // Now define it to return the id, because we want to know what id was generated for the Business
    returning Business.map(_.businessId)
  // And we define a transformation for the returned value, which combines our original parameters with the
  // returned id
    into((userIdAndBusiness, id) => BusinessRow(id, userIdAndBusiness._1, userIdAndBusiness._2, userIdAndBusiness._3, userIdAndBusiness._4, userIdAndBusiness._5, userIdAndBusiness._6))
  // And finally, insert the business into the database
  ) +=(businessInput.userId, businessInput.name, businessInput.location, businessInput.address, businessInput.phonenumber, businessInput.email)
// Insert a sequence of BusinessHours objects 
    _ = for(businessHours <- businessInput.hours) BusinessHours += BusinessHoursRow(businessRow.businessId, businessHours.weekDay, businessHours.startTime, businessHours.endTime)

  } yield (businessRow)
  )
```

Here is a print out of what the hours field looks like:

```
hours -> Vector(ListMap(weekDay -> 1, startTime -> 07:00, endTime -> 10:00), ListMap(weekDay -> 2, startTime -> 07:00, endTime -> 10:00))
```

And now I am getting the following error:

```
scala.collection.immutable.ListMap$Node cannot be cast to dao.BusinessHoursInput
```

Comment: I'm confused how you start the code with `_ <-`, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Please have first a look at the [Scala collections doc](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html) and how the Scala philosophy is about immutability (rather than mutation like `+=`).

Answer (score 1):

If this line is inside a for-yield comprehension, you need to change the first `<-` to `=`. Because `BusinessHours += ...` returns `Unit`, and `_ <-` is desugared into `flatMap` or `map`.

Alternatively you can put `BusinessHours += ...` in `yield`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a for comprehension that is translated into a `map`. And map needs to transform `hours: Seq[BusinessHoursInput]` into something else.
Inside the map you are doing this: `BusinessHours += BusinessHoursRow(businessRow.businessId, businessHours.weekDay, businessHours.startTime, businessHours.endTime)`
This option doesn't transform the `hours` into something else. It is adding a `BusinessHoursRow` into `BusinessHours` and that operation return Unit.

So how to solve it?

1) Transform `BusinessHoursInput` into `BusinessHoursRow` and then insert them in `BusinessHours`:

```
var businessHoursRows = businessInput.hours.map { businessHoursInput =>
    BusinessHoursRow(businessHoursInput.businessId, businessHoursInput.weekDay, 
    businessHoursInput.startTime, businessHoursInput.endTime)
}
BusinessHours ++= businessHoursRows
```

2) Use `foreach` instead of `map`:

```
businessInput.hours.foreach { businessHoursInput =>
     businessHoursRows += BusinessHoursRow(businessHoursInput.businessId, businessHoursInput.weekDay, 
    businessHoursInput.startTime, businessHoursInput.endTime)
}
```